# How can I know if user has opened Notification List?

Tags: android, notifications

I am working in an application implementing an AccesibilityService, to detect when other applications are sending notifications. That is easy to do extending `AccesibilityService` class.

Now I would like to know, when the user opens the Notification List, but I have not found any documentation about it. The only similar thing is using new `NotificationListenerService` but I'm not sure if it can help. Also, my app is for 2.2+ devices, and the use of this class is for level 18+ .. (I think).

My question is if there is another way to know from my application if user have opened the notificationlist.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no. you cannot be informed when user pulled down notification area.